# Java method not working, causing program to hang

Tags: java, class, methods

Hi I'm writing a program that will analyse a block of text, specifically reading a file and counting the number of lines, words and numbers inside that file.

I have tried count the number of lines in a separate class within a method and then tried to call that method in the main class to print the total number of lines in the file, however this does not work as I expected and causes the program to hang when I have tried to call the line count method. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Main Class:

```
package cw;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextAnalyser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LineCounter object = new LineCounter();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(TextAnalyser.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt"));
        int totalNumbers = 0;
        int totalDigits = 0;
        int totalWordCount = 0;
        int totalLines = 0;

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            totalWordCount++;

            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                totalDigits += sc.nextInt();
                totalNumbers++;
            }
            else {
                sc.next();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The total of all digits added = " + totalDigits);
        System.out.println("The total number of digits in the file = " + totalNumbers);
        System.out.println("The total number of words in the file = " + totalWordCount);
        object.TotalLines();
    }
}
```

Line counting class:

```
package cw;
import java.util.Scanner;
//Class that counts the lines in a file.
public class LineCounter {
    public static void TotalLines() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(TextAnalyser.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt"));
        System.out.println("hi");
        int linetotal = 0;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            linetotal++;
        }

        System.out.println(linetotal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hasNextLine() does only tell you IF there is a next line - it does not read it. So you are standing at the beginning and asking "is there a next line?" again and again and again... You should try actually reading it via nextLine();

Comment: That is what I want it to do though, shouldn't it increment linetotal each time there is a line, ie it is true ?

Comment: You want it to ask if there is a first line over and over again? What do you want to count? How often you can ask if there is a first line? If you want to count the lines this way, ask if there is another one, read it (and thus move the "pointer" to the next line), repeat.

Comment: Okay I understand, you helped a lot I just added sc.nextLine(); into the while, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`just add` this `line of code` :

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
          String sentence = sc.nextLine();
          linetotal++;
      }
```

in your  `public static void TotalLines(){` method...

this way you `actually get the next line`, `not only` asking *whether there exists another line* in your `while` (which `always` returns `true` and you `never` exit the while loop!)